# Printer only prints to default printer

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument, printdialog

Here is the code I use (just the printing-related part):

Button 1 onclick handler method:

```
printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
printDialog1.AllowPrintToFile = true;
printDialog1.PrintToFile = false;
if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 826, 1169);
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}
```

And my pd_PrintPage method:

```
Bitmap bitmapCanvas = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapCanvas);
g.Clear(Color.White);
...
some g.Draw...() stuff

...
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmapCanvas, A(2), A(2));
//where e is the PrintPageEventArgs defined in the method signature
```

First part of my problem is that, this doesn't print to the selected printer (selected on the print dialog).
It only prints to a printer if that is the default printer.
Under Windows 7 it works, it recognizes the default printer, so the default printer will be selected by default in the comboBox on the print dialog which comes up after I click the button.

My main problem is that, this doesn't work under Windows Xp at all (unfortunately I only can use that). And I'm kind of curious why. So I don't know if I made a mess, or it is not supported under Windows Xp.

With what should I complete or correct my code?

Any help is appreciated and thank you very much!
Mitulat bati

Comment: What were you expecting? Use the PrinterSettings property.

Comment: What do you think I was expecting?
What properties should I set to reach my aim?

Comment: What I told you to use, `PrintDocument.PrinterSettings`.

Comment: You create the PrintDialog but then never use it,  when you are editing your paper size you would want to operate on the printDialog1.Document Property you just create a new one which is likely to use your default printer.

Comment: newStackExchangeInstance: PrinterSettings is a class which has properties. My question was about those properties... but I think now I see it. Thank you!

Comment: Bearcat9425: you mean, that I should use the values of the PrintDialog  in the "if" section? For example: printDocument.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings; ?

Comment: What I mean is you create the dialog and go through all that trouble and use nothing from it.  You could do that or do what I posted below as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
printDialog1.AllowPrintToFile = true;
printDialog1.PrintToFile = false;
if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    printDialog1.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 826, 1169);
    printDialog1.Document.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
    printDialog1.Document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    printDialog1.Document.Print();
}
```

Comment: But, I think in the meantime I found a solution. That both of you said:
printDocument.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
Anyway... I will figure whether it works or not out tomorrow.

Comment: The difference is that you created a new PrintDocument in your if statement that just used the default settings, mine uses the document from your print dialog where you chose the new print and apply your settings that are needed.